# Simple way to send message to Azure Event Hub - second approach

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

My first approach was to use the `com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs:3.2.0` dependency but I had the following problem: [Client hangs when calling Azure Event Hub and facing connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63039023/client-hangs-when-calling-azure-event-hub-and-facing-connection-error)

So my 2nd approach can be

- either to use another dependency (I need to use OAuth2 too) -> unfortunately I haven't found any
- or don't use a dependency but code the message sending myself -> it might be a big task

Could you please recommend me library that supports OAuth2?
Or a sample code which supports message sending to Event Hub over AMQP with OAuth2?
Or a 3rd approach ...?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your hang issue, I posted a new answer in the original thread [Client hangs when calling Azure Event Hub and facing connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63039023/client-hangs-when-calling-azure-event-hub-and-facing-connection-error). **That should fix your issue**.

Now coming back to this question, primarily you should follow the [latest tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-java-send-v2) (uses Event Hub v5 sdk using Producer/Consumer pattern).

```
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.*;

public class Sender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String connectionString = "EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING";
        final String eventHubName = "EVENT HUB NAME";

        // create a producer using the namespace connection string and event hub name
        EventHubProducerClient producer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName)
            .buildProducerClient();

        // prepare a batch of events to send to the event hub    
        EventDataBatch batch = producer.createBatch();
        batch.tryAdd(new EventData("First event"));
        batch.tryAdd(new EventData("Second event"));
        batch.tryAdd(new EventData("Third event"));
        batch.tryAdd(new EventData("Fourth event"));
        batch.tryAdd(new EventData("Fifth event"));

        // send the batch of events to the event hub
        producer.send(batch);

        // close the producer
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

Regarding the question on OAuth2, it is very much possible to leverage AAD authentication approach instead of Shared Access Signature (the default connection string approach). You can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authenticate-managed-identity?tabs=latest) for Managed Identity scenario OR [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authenticate-application) for custom AAD application based auth.

Regarding the recommendation on OAuth2 library, the first party choice in the Azure world would be [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) for seamless integration and support.

Regarding the question on writing the whole thing by custom code, while it's technically possible, but honestly it's super impractical to invest on this mammoth task due to following reasons:

1. Why to reinvent the wheel?
2. It will increase your maintenance headache for a hell lot of custom code which does only technical wiring, but hardly adds any value to the business.
3. You would be pretty much on your own to figure out any issue or future compatibility.
4. Adding all the low level AMQP and OAuth handling in your code would add unnecessary burden to your team to master those.
5. ..and most importantly it would cost Money and Time :)

Using standard libraries not only saves you from lot of efforts and money, but ensures reusability, and support from both the creator and communities.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! The thought (to rewrite the message sending mechanism to Azure) was mainly driven by the desperation that I couldn't circumvent the hanging issue with the `azure-eventhubs` dependency. However you helped me in my other post (thanks for that again!) and you also recommended an updated library so this question is not valid anymore. I hope the OAuth2 works well with `com.microsoft.azure:msal4j` too. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Yes com.microsoft.azure:msal4j is the Java flavour of MSAL which is the only Microsoft-supported one for Java and works well for OAuth2 in Azure AD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries#microsoft-supported-client-libraries

Comment: why no one showing how to send message with json? 90% eventhub use case is to ingest data to database.